# Line defined by yvalues and the number of xticks

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

Is it possible to plot the line defined by yvalue and the number of xticks?

Line from point to point using matplotlib is:

```
plt.plot([1, 6.46786], [2, 1.69241])
```

is it possible to replace the first numbers in [ ] by xticks counter? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use np.arange for x axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#  these are the numbers you want to plot
ys = np.array([6.46786, 1.69241])

#  these will be x axis ticks
xs = np.arange(len(ys))

plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain it to me more? `Print(len(ys))` gives 2, so why the line goes from the first tick to the second? How to connect the second ticks and the third ticks? I tried `xs = np.arange(len(ys)+1)` that does not work

Comment: The more values your ys has, the more points will be plotted. So if you want a "third thick" you need a third value in ys array.

Comment: "so why the line goes from the first tick to the second?", by default plt.plot connects sequential points with straight lines: eg if you have ys = [6.4, 1.69, 3.12] and xs = [0, 1, 2], it will create line from (0, 6.4) to (1, 1.69), then a second line from (1, 1.69) to (2, 3.12).

Comment: Thank you. I have a file with 4 columns that mean coordinates (x1,y1) for start point, (x2,y2) for end point. I need to plot lots of lines that connect these two points. It has different y values and x values are xtics next to. Could you recommend me a cycle for this?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to plot all lines in the file on the same plot?

Comment: Yes, there is about 200 rows in that file and I would like to plot about 200 lines to the same plot

Comment: If you perform multiple plt.plot without doing plt.show, it will draw all lines to the same figure, just do a single show after all plots.

Comment: I don't know load data to lists? I have let's say 20 lines connecting xtics 1 and 2, but 6 lines connecting 2 and 3. So, if I sorted rows in file to reach order of lines like 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, lots of lines will be left over.

Comment: If you somehow show the file (maybe via pastebin) it would be better.

Comment: Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259923/plotting-lines-in-cycle-according-ticks I wrote a new question

Comment: Is it posiible in some way?

Comment: If all your line segments are independent, try this: https://pastebin.com/6ve7jGMx , if you would like to print connected line segments with same color it will take some more work I guess.

Comment: Could you please send me the link again? There is that This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff. I would like to print only black lines.