# How to plot line segments or vectors with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a file with 4 columns that mean, coordinates (x1, y1) for start point, (x2, y2) for end point. I need to plot lots of lines that connect these two points. It has different y values, and x values are numbers of xtics next to. Could you recommend me a cycle for plotting these lines in the same plot?

```
2 11.6414 3 9.2395
3 9.23494 4 8.43797
3 9.2395 4 8.43797
1 6.46786 2 1.69241
1 8.76289 2 1.69241
1 8.76289 2 7.04954
2 11.6414 3 9.2395
3 9.2395 4 8.43797
4 10.3475 5 9.69117
4 10.7528 5 9.69117
4 10.7528 5 10.3576
4 11.0156 5 9.69117
5 11.199 6 11.021
1 6.46786 2 1.69241
1 8.76289 2 1.69241
4 11.3245 5 11.199
5 11.199 6 11.021
6 11.021 5 9.69117
6 11.021 5 10.3576
```

After advise I have

```
dfr = pd.read_csv('souradnice.csv')
dfr.columns = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2']

dfr['dx'] = dfr.x2 - dfr.x1  # rozdíl x-ovových hodnot
dfr['dy'] = dfr.y2 - dfr.y1  # rozdíl y-ových hodnot

q = ax.quiver(dfr.x1, dfr.y1, dfr.dx, dfr.dy, units='xy', scale=1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html):

- Using quiver requires calculating `dx` and `dy`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('souradnice.csv',
                 header=None,
                 names=['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'],
                 dtype='float')  # add sep=' ' if values are space separated
df['dx'] = df.x2 - df.x1
df['dy'] = df.y2 - df.y1

 x1        y1  x2        y2  dx       dy
  2  11.64140   3   9.23950   1 -2.40190
  3   9.23494   4   8.43797   1 -0.79697
  3   9.23950   4   8.43797   1 -0.80153
  1   6.46786   2   1.69241   1 -4.77545
  1   8.76289   2   1.69241   1 -7.07048
  1   8.76289   2   7.04954   1 -1.71335
  2  11.64140   3   9.23950   1 -2.40190
  3   9.23950   4   8.43797   1 -0.80153
  4  10.34750   5   9.69117   1 -0.65633
  4  10.75280   5   9.69117   1 -1.06163
  4  10.75280   5  10.35760   1 -0.39520
  4  11.01560   5   9.69117   1 -1.32443
  5  11.19900   6  11.02100   1 -0.17800
  1   6.46786   2   1.69241   1 -4.77545
  1   8.76289   2   1.69241   1 -7.07048
  4  11.32450   5  11.19900   1 -0.12550
  5  11.19900   6  11.02100   1 -0.17800
  6  11.02100   5   9.69117  -1 -1.32983
  6  11.02100   5  10.35760  -1 -0.66340
```

#### Plot:

- Review the `quiver` documentation, as there are a number of parameters for changing the appearance of the lines and arrows.
- [Advanced quiver and quiverkey functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-demo-py)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
q = ax.quiver(df.x1, df.y1, df.dx, df.dy, units='xy', scale=1)

plt.grid()

ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

- This plot shows the entire dataset of more 1600 vectors